# Search Engine Crawler call ajax to crawl ajax returned content?

Tags: seo, ajax

wondering if search engine crawlers see pages with links to ajax calls (using jQuery + Asp.Net MVC)  if they follow these links to index the content.

I found [this](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/1991/status-of-crawlable-ajax) question, but I am wondering currently does the 'follow' work with standard jQuery type links on say click events.

Should the website put ajax content in a static and perhaps point to that page from a sitemap? This would be a non ajax page.

Just trying to get the most content indexed that I get to improve my organic seo.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ajax content is not currently crawlable ([but this may change](http://googlewebmastercentral.blogspot.com/2009/10/proposal-for-making-ajax-crawlable.html)) so if you don't make that content available to non-JavaScript enabled users, which includes search engines, it won't be reachable and thus not indexed.

This is a basic accessibility issue. If your content cannot be retrieved without JavaScript enabled then your site is not very accessible. Accessibility is a big part of SEO as search engines are very needy users accessibility-wise. Not mention you are leaving much of your content unavailable to users without JavaScript enabled or available to them.

You should be using [progressive enhancement](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Progressive_enhancement) when constructing your sites. First make it available to everybody and then go back and add enhancements that may not be available to some users but will enhance the experience of those who can experience it (i.e. JavaScript).

Comment: +1 for progressive enhancement - hiding content behind AJAX is even worse than hiding it in a Flash movie. Apparently there's some disagreement upon whether Google is *presently* crawling AJAX content which meets its specifications ... would be interested to know whether anyone has access logs which show (or don't show) Google acting upon that proposal.

Answer (score 1):

You can facilitate Google's indexing of your Ajax state pages by following the protocol described here:  http://code.google.com/web/ajaxcrawling/docs/getting-started.html

Unfortunately, the protocol is not supported by Bing, as of now.

Answer (score 0):

"Should the website put ajax content in a static and perhaps point to that page from a sitemap? This would be a non ajax page." I believe this is precisely the best thing to do and also what google recommends at the moment besides the standard sitemap implementations (a link can be found [here](http://www.google.com/support/webmasters/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=174992)). John also suggested this in one of the posts.